# Check if Steam game requires an update via command line

Tags: steam

I have a dedicated server of a Steam game running on my Windows machine, and I want to keep it up-to-date.

I would like to periodically check to see if an update is available and, if so, install it, inform users the server is being restarted, and restart the server.

Problem is, I do not know how to **check whether an update is available**.

There is a command line utility called SteamCMD, but it's not clear how to use this just to check whether the server needs updating - it seems to only be able to tell something to update, not check whether it needs to.

**How can I do either of these things via command line?**

- **Check whether a Steam app needs updating**, or
- Update a Steam app, then **know whether an update has occurred**

Comment: Which gameserver have you installed??

Comment: V Rising, but does that make a difference?

Comment: Not all games use the SteamPipe content system. Have a look at https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD maybe that helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461871/getting-steam-game-version-number-to-check-if-update-is-available

Comment: https://github.com/mathphreak/node-steamcmd/issues/4

Comment: And perhaps https://steamapi.xpaw.me/ my guess is that the stackoverflow link gives the easiest and most reliable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch script worked great for me. It uses curl to query the server to find out if the build changed, and steamapp to install the new version. This will be overly zealous installing if there's a new beta release or something, but I don't really care for my purposes - more could be done to extract the precise build ID needed if required.

It requires to be passed the AppID (available from the Properties of the game in Steam, right click menu) as well as the installation directory.

The script, when called, will return 1 if an update is required, 0 if no update is required, and -1 if there was an error. It requires steamapp/steamapp.exe to exist relative to the batch script.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET RETVALUE=-1

IF "%1"=="" (
    ECHO ERROR: Please provide Steam App ID as first parameter
    GOTO END
)

IF "%2"=="" (
    ECHO ERROR: Please provide app directory as second parameter - likely within steamapps\common
    GOTO END
)

SET APP_INSTALL_DIR=%2\

IF NOT EXIST !APP_INSTALL_DIR! (
    ECHO ERROR: Install directory not found: !APP_INSTALL_DIR! 
    GOTO END
)

SET STEAMCMD=%~dp0\steamcmd\steamcmd.exe

IF NOT EXIST !STEAMCMD! (
    ECHO Expected: steamcmd located in !STEAMCMD!
    GOTO END
)

SET APPID=%1
SET APPINFO_DIR=%~dp0\appinfo
SET APPINFO_FILE=!APPINFO_DIR!\!APPID!
SET APPINFO_FILE_NEW=!APPINFO_FILE!-new

IF NOT EXIST !APPINFO_DIR!\ MKDIR !APPINFO_DIR!

ECHO Checking for needed updates for game id !APPID!

CALL curl https://api.steamcmd.net/v1/info/!APPID! --silent --output !APPINFO_FILE_NEW!
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Error getting app info for game
    GOTO END
)

SET NEEDS_UPDATE=1
IF EXIST !APPINFO_FILE! (
    CALL FC !APPINFO_FILE! !APPINFO_FILE_NEW! > NUL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 SET NEEDS_UPDATE=0
)

IF !NEEDS_UPDATE! NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Update required, installing to !APP_INSTALL_DIR!
    CALL !STEAMCMD! +force_install_dir !APP_INSTALL_DIR! +login anonymous +app_update !APPID! validate +quit 
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Error updating app via steamcmd
        GOTO END
    )
    
    MOVE !APPINFO_FILE_NEW! !APPINFO_FILE! > NUL

    ECHO Version out-of-date, returning 1
    SET RETVALUE=1
    GOTO END
) ELSE (
    ECHO Version up-to-date, returning 0
    DEL !APPINFO_FILE_NEW!
    SET RETVALUE=0
    GOTO END
)

:END

EXIT /B !RETVALUE!
```

I was able to use this in a separate batch script, run periodically, to check for a new update and, if there was one, count down to and perform a restart.